# Could ossicone-horns be useful?

Tags: anatomy, natural-defenses

Ossicone-horns would, as the name implies, combine ossicones and horns. Specifically, they would be branched like an antler or more complex ossicone, but with the end-segments being covered in a sharp keratinous sheath like a horn. Like horns and ossicones, the structure is kept permanently

Could these ossicone-horns be useful to a ruminant for defense, at least moreso than other pecoran head-bones?

Comment: Not really worth answering as written: all you've done is propose growing horn from skin that ordinarily grows hair. Basically, you just reinvented the cow. Or the cowkapi. The obvious answer here is "yes".

Comment: @elemtilas It's not 'just a cow'. Horns are straight and often self-similar to some degree. The proposed structure combines an antler's complexity with a horn's sharpness, forming a unique structure

Comment: Doesn't much matter what the particular shape is. Typologically, a bit of bone sticking off a skull with skin and hair on it is an "ossicone" (like a giraffe); and an ossicone with some horn on it is pretty much a cow. The "complexity" you describe is window dressing. That is, the "unique structure" doesn't actually alter the question or the answer in any way. The end form could be a straight ossicone with horn or it could be a fractal ossicone with horn. Six of one, half dozen of the other.

Comment: Do you require them to be strictly for defence? There's a lot of precedent for over-opulent growths as a display of sexual fitness; if you would like these ossicone horns, perhaps they serve the dual purpose of sexual signalling and combat, and they arose as normal horns evolved into an intricate structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to keep it short, it wouldn't really make much of a difference, since the point of horns and ossicones is to apply force on a small area to puncture the enemy, something giraffes already do.

At most it will make them a little more easy to pierce with, but not to much since the key to piercing is the force used, not the object.